# How to install update to Extension in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have created the extension with `<SystemComponent>true</SystemComponent>`

I have added this tag so it will not show on the Extension Manager. But now its not allowing me to install the latest version, and throws `SystemComponentException`.

If I remove `<SystemComponent>` from the manifest, it will allow me to update the existing extension.

Is there anyway to update the extension with this `<SystemComponent>true</SystemComponent>` tag?

Manifest looks like this:

```
<Identifier Id="1053D167-FD56-4EEB-B920-610B0295D0FD">
<Name xml:space="preserve">TEST</Name>
<Author>Ganesh</Author>
<Version>6.1.7</Version>
<Description xml:space="preserve">Test</Description>     
<Locale>1033</Locale>
<InstalledByMsi>false</InstalledByMsi>
...
...
...
<AllUsers>true</AllUsers>
<SystemComponent>true</SystemComponent>
</Identifier>
```

Comment: Why did you set SystemComponent? It's typically only set if you're installing extensions via MSI or some third-party technology and so you want the install to be managed by it.

Comment: My requirement is just hide the extension from extension manager. I found that adding system component hides it. but i can't install updates to that extension.